# How to add prefix(scheme&host&port) for script and css tags in html-webpack-plugin?

Tags: webpack, html-webpack-plugin

Currently, I know this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet"></head>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="app">
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

I want the script and css tags injected like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <link href="http://cdn.foo.com/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet"></head>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="app">
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.foo.com/js/main.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

The others keep the same. i.e.(output files may be saved locally as usual)

Answer (score 0):

Seems no options. I inject several lines to the source code and solve this problem by:

```
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    prefix: 'http://cdn.foo.com',
  })
```

These lines are totally harmless if you don't set `prefix` option(actually seems harmless even if you set it). More info check this [pr](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/pull/701).